# Windows 7 Pro blue screen Event Viewer Event ID 10

Tags: eventviewer

I have a user who's Windows 7 Pro machine repeatedly blue screens and the Event Viewer has numerous entries like below that seem to occur about the time of the BSOD occurrences. I would appreciate any help in understanding if this entry might be giving some useful information to troubleshoot these blue screens.

Event viewer message:

> Event filter with query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "Win32_Processor" AND TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99" could not be reactivated in namespace "//./root/CIMV2" because of error 0x80041003. Events cannot be delivered through this filter until the problem is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

This is a WMI event. It may (or may not) be associated with the BSOD (my guess is that it isn't, since this event doesn't normally cause BSODs). Event 10 should be fixable with [KB 2545227](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2545227).

If that isn't the problem, then more information would be needed (obviously). Looking at the event viewer is not enough. You need to examine the BSOD itself. Specifically, the STOP message would be useful. With that message alone, Google will tell you the general issue 90% of the time. If you need more details, you'll need to analyze the dump file; [this link](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/windows-bsod.html) will take you to a site that shows you how to do it with different tools.